# How to extract common words from two files where one contains a PL/SQL block while the other is a list of functions used - in UNIX?

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a file say input_sql in unix.

The file A looks like :

yifi.yifi_bdcr_process_ log @BHOR.AB.CTT.COM

GROUP BY vdr_date;

RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20004, 'pqi_sector_daily_v1 data not available. record_cnt is ' || record_cnt);

FROM rtb.s_rtb3_gsm_usid_dy@MAXIMA_M62085_LNK.DB.ATT.COM

RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20004, 's_btb4_gsm_usid_dy data not available. record_cnt is ' || record_cnt);

,nvl(a.useid, b.useid) as useid

AND cm_usid <> 'UNASSIGNED';

Prompt Updating Process table log

DELETE FROM cqi_imp_metric_process_log

INSERT INTO cqi_imp_metric_process_log

TRUNC(SYSDATE),

SYSDATE,

I have another file B having text like:

INSERT

LOG

GROUP BY

NVL

TRUNC

SYSDATE

LOG

LN

SIGN

I wish to extract the common words between the two files (Select, insert etc.) in UNIX.

The Output should be like in a third file C:

GROUP BY

||

||

TRUNC

NVL

TRUNC

SYSDATE

TRUNC

SYSDATE

Thanks :)

PS : Using the solution given, LOG, SIGN, LN are getting included in the third file which are coming from  cqi_imp_metric_process_**log**, AND cm_usid <> 'UNAS**SIGN**ED'; @MAXIMA_M62085_**LN**K.DB.ATT.COM respectively. I do not wish to include these texts.

Comment: `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}{for(i in a)if(toupper($0)~toupper(i))print i}' fileA fileB`

Comment: Hi Jidder - Could you please explain the above command?

Comment: I'm sure jotne can seeing as his answer is exactly the same :)

Comment: yeah but he has not replied yet. Any of you guys could please explain the steps involved? :P Jotne??

Comment: I am facing a slight problem Jidder. Suppose the pattern file has a   function name which has two words (eg. GROUP BY). When I am using your solution it is simply showing GROUP and not the entire text. I have another line in the query having TRUNC(SYSDATE) which are both present in the pattern file. When I am replacing $1 by $0, GROUP BY is showing but TRUNC function is not getting listed. Please help.

Comment: `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}{for(i in a)if(toupper($0)~toupper(i))print i}' fileA fileB`

Comment: Hi Jidder, Please see the updated example. I have tried toggling between 0 and 1. When I am including 0 Group by is showing but Trunc is not getting listed.

Comment: and also I would like to include the excat words, not just pattern. LN (present in FILE B) is getting listed as it is present in file A in the form of "FROM rtb.s_rtb3_gsm_usid_dy@MAXIMA_M62085_LNK.DB.ATT.COM" . Atleast please provide a solution for this

Comment: leave this question how it was and make a new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0];next} {for (i in a) if (tolower($0)~tolower(i)) print}' pattern fileA
**INSERT /*+APPEND */ INTO ABC_IMP_SEC_DAILY_STG
SELECT
```

---

`gnu awk` version:

```
awk -vIGNORECASE=1 'FNR==NR {a[$0];next} {for (i in a) if ($0~i) print}' pattern fileA
**INSERT /*+APPEND */ INTO ABC_IMP_SEC_DAILY_STG
SELECT
```

Comment: Hi Jotne, Your approach was more or less accurate. But i do not need the entire line. I just want to extract the common functions from text A. Like only Insert (not the entire text)

Comment: I am facing a slight problem Jotne. Suppose the pattern file has a   function name which has two words (eg. GROUP BY). When I am using your solution it is simply showing GROUP and not the entire text. I have another line in the query having TRUNC(SYSDATE) which are both present in the pattern file. When I am replacing $1 by $0, GROUP BY is showing but TRUNC function is not getting listed. Please help.

Comment: @ArnabRoy This solution reads the pattern file line by line and store them in an array `a`. It does not matter if its one word or a sentence. Then it test one and one line from your `fileA` against all the data in array `a`.  If found, just print the corresponding line from `fileA`. Can you update your example.

Answer (score 1):

Try using grep as below:

```
grep -iof pattern_file.txt fileA.txt
```

- Grep - will search for pattern defined in file called pattern_file.txt which goes with -f parmeter from within file fileA.txt. While -i is to ignore the case.-o will just print the matched pattern.

Comment: i think you need to add `o` parameter.

Comment: TBH i am not sure if he just needs the selected words or whole line. Anyways thanks for your comment and i have added comment in my answer for the same.

Comment: I don't need the whole line, I simply need the functions that are common to both text A and text B

Comment: `grep -iof pattern_file.txt fileA.txt`